# How to suppress "There are still active COM objects in this application" error when closing application?

Tags: c++, windows, c++builder, atl, vcl

I've written a few ATL COM objects that are used for drag-and-drop within my C++ Builder application.

Due to reasons beyond my control, my application still has active COM objects when the user attempts to close it.  This is because other COM clients that use my objects seem to cache my COM objects and don't release them - as a result, my COM objects still have a reference count greater than zero when the user clicks the "X" to close my program.  This results in the user getting an unfriendly message like this:

[image]

I would like my application to silently terminate and not ask the user this annoying question.

How do I suppress this message?

Comment: You can't, terminating your process will make those other apps fail.  You are supposed to destroy all your windows and keep running until the last object's reference count goes to 0.  Finding out if that's the case is a C++ Builder implementation detail.  Ought to visible when you attach a debugger when this dialog is up and look at the call stack.

Comment: @Hans: in an ideal world, you would be right, and I should never ask this question.  Too bad other applications like Windows Explorer are ill-behaved and hang on to objects long after they should have been released.  It's bad for my COM server to pop up confusing messages just because another client is ill-behaved (or actually expects that the COM server might be closed, as Explorer probably anticipates - I'm not having problems with Explorer crashing, for example).  See my related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7600556/

Comment: Or another way I have observed this message is that my own application could be holding references that are going to be correctly freed in the main form destructor, but because C++ Builder makes these checks in the form close query event, the user gets prompted with this message anyway!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The popup message is displayed by the the `TATLModule::AutomationTerminateProc()` callback function in atlmod.h.  It is registered by the `TATLModule::InitATLServer()` callback, which calls the VCL's `AddTerminateProc()` function.  When the `TForm::Close()` method is called, it calls `CallTerminationProcs()` to see if the app can safely close, which then calls `TATLModule::AutomationTerminateProc()`.

The `TATLModule` constructor calls `InitATLServer()` if you do not provide your own initialization callback.  So to avoid the popup, simply pass in a custom callback in your project's main .cpp file that does everything `TATLModule::InitATLServer()` normally does other than call `AddTerminateProc()`, eg:

```
void __fastcall MyInitATLServer();

TComModule _ProjectModule(&MyInitATLServer); // <-- here
TComModule &_Module = _ProjectModule;

BEGIN_OBJECT_MAP(ObjectMap)
  ...
END_OBJECT_MAP()

void __fastcall MyInitATLServer()
{
    if (TComModule::SaveInitProc)
        TComModule::SaveInitProc();

    _Module.Init(ObjectMap, Sysinit::HInstance);
    _Module.m_ThreadID = ::GetCurrentThreadId();
    _Module.m_bAutomationServer = true;
    _Module.DoFileAndObjectRegistration();
    // AddTerminationProc(AutomationTerminationProc); // <-- no more popup!
}
```

Comment: Sounds like another equally-valid solution to the one I used in my answer.  As far as I can tell, it looks like it has the same downside as mine: heavy reliance on internal VCL implementation.  So I'll keep using mine as it's simpler and I already did it.  But I'll go ahead and accept your answer, as it shows some good research that I did as well but didn't bother writing up, and it better explains why my answer works.

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround for this.  I'll leave this question open in case anyone posts a better method, since this one is dependent on undocumented internal implementation details of C++ Builder's ATL/VCL libraries.

In the main form, place:

```
extern TComModule &_Module;
void __fastcall TMainAppForm::FormCloseQuery(TObject *Sender, bool &CanClose)
{
    _Module.m_nLockCnt = 0;
```

VCL appears to check the lock count and display this annoying message *after* the close query event is raised.  It only displays the message if the lock count is 0.  Therefore, I set the lock count to 0 which causes the message to not be shown.  I think it's harmless to do, because I searched the ATL/VCL source code for places where the lock count is used, and I didn't find anything other than the code that checks whether to display this message.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
TerminateProcess(GetCurrentProcess(), 0);
```

Of course, if there is no better way.

Comment: Two issues this raises are: (1) where is the most ideal place to put this code that suppresses this message? (2) it seems to punish and prevent all resources in the entire app from cleaning up, just because one of them was ill-behaved.