# Can I suppress this message? >> One or more applications are using the iTunes scripting interface

Tags: c#, windows, api, com, itunes

I am writing a small C Sharp program to interface with iTunes using the iTunes Windows COM api. My program has to be running before iTunes starts up and after iTunes closes down. I want it to detect when iTunes closes down using the OnQuittingEvent.

```
    private void itunes_OnQuittingEvent()
    {
        // Remove any handlers from the iTunes COM object.
        app.OnPlayerPlayEvent -= itunes_OnPlayerPlayEvent;
        app.OnQuittingEvent -= itunes_OnQuittingEvent;
        bniTunesRunning = false;
        // Release the COM object.
        app = null;
        Console.WriteLine("iTunes Closing!");
    }
```

However with my c sharp program running, when I close down iTunes I get a warning message: "One or more applications are using the iTunes scripting interface" and then a 20 second countdown before iTunes closes.

My Question:
Can I use iTunes Windows COM OnQuittingEvent event handler to sort of un-instantiate the iTunesApp object reference in my C sharp code at the point of me closing down the iTunes application and thus not have that warning message appear on screen?? Is there a way to just suppress that warning message altogether?

A similar question was asked here: [How to suppress "There are still active COM objects in this application" error when closing application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7601204/how-to-suppress-there-are-still-active-com-objects-in-this-application-error-w) but the code is C++ not C Sharp.

Thank you.

Comment: Why not try translating the C++ version to C#? If you run into problems, update your question and people here can try to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

To prevent the dialog you need to decrement the runtime callable wrapper reference count, and then force collection of your iTunesAppClass reference. For more detail see post by user Bonj [here](http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/244472-how-release-close-com-object). Unlike in their example I found it wasn't necessary to set the iTunesAppClass reference to null before collecting. Might depend on your implementation however. I also found I didn't have to decrement the RCW in a loop as I only ever have one COM object referenced. Here's an example that works in my application:

```
var app = new iTunesLib.iTunesAppClass();

// do stuff

System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(app);
System.GC.Collect();
```